# C# regex Unrecognized escape sequence

Tags: c#

I want to extract 099% from the line Bat:4.16/099% check if it is greater then 95 and replace 099% with High

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Your code goes here



            var my_string = "XXXXXXXXX" + "YYYYYYYYY" + "Bat:4.16/099%" + "BIT:7" + "AAAAAAAA" + "BBBBBBBBB" + "CCCCCCCCC";

            //I want to extract 099% from the line Bat:4.16/099% check if it is greater then 95 and replace 099% with High

            //The below code doesn't seem to replace at all. I don't know how to replace the second digit group alone with High
            Console.WriteLine(my_string);

            Regex regex_bat = new Regex("Bat:[^.*]\/[^\d+$]"); 
            my_string = regex_bat.Replace(my_string, "High"); 

            Console.WriteLine(my_string);
        }
    }
}

(26:52) Unrecognized escape sequence
(26:56) Unrecognized escape sequence
```

Comment: The regex pattern you really want is `@"(?<=Bat:.*?\/)\d+%"`

Comment: i.e. match 1 or more digits then `%` only if preceded by `Bat:blah/`

Comment: @how do I check if it is greater than 095 or not? If less than 95 I want to say low

Comment: Please do not start a chameleon question. You have the answer for your "Unrecognized escape sequence" question. If you have a different question that you need help on, feel free to open one.

Comment: Hint: Use a `MatchEvaluator` delegate https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
 Regex regex_bat = new Regex("Bat:[^.*]\\//[^\\d+$]");
```

This will replace from  099% to "High";

```
String getArr = my_string.Replace('%', '/');
String[] splt = getArr.Split('/');

if (int.Parse(splt[1].ToString()) > 95)
 { 
    splt[1] = "High";
 }
 string result = splt[0] + splt[1] + splt[2];
```

result = "XXXXXXXXXYYYYYYYYYBat:4.16HighBIT:7AAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCC"

Comment: @reds - The errors are now gone.But the next line is not replacing

Comment: what do you mean next line. What output do you need?

Comment: @reds - I want to extract `099%` from the line `Bat:4.16/099%` check if it is greater then `95` and replace `099%` with `High` .I don't know how to replace the second `digit group` alone with `High`